# Weather Stripping seal 1/2 inch kerf door gap

Tags: doors, sealing, weatherstripping

It seems the doors in my home are "kerf" sealed, and the best option is the get a thicker seal? How are the widths of the seals measured?

[image: seal]

[image: gap]

Comment: Personally, I'd consider shimming/rehanging the door to close most of that gap. Thick weatherstripping is available, but it won't be pretty. ... Or, as an alternative, install a good storm door and let it provide the air seal while this door provides security; I've done that on one door.

Comment: It looks like the strike at the latch just needs to be moved in a bit....